# custom log4j2 appender is not working in java 11

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I am working on a spring-boot (2.1.9.RELEASE) application with JAVA-11 and using the log4j2, version is 2.12.1. I am using custom log4j2 appenders which actually save the logs in DB.  I tried with below snippet but it is not working.

```
public class TestApplication {
  static {
    System.setProperty("org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem", "none");
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
   }
   @Bean
   public ApplicationContextProvider applicationContextProvider() {
      return new ApplicationContextProvider();
   }
}
```

And log4j2.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration status="warn" monitorInterval="30" packages="test.package">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="system_out" packages="test.package">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %t %x [%X{process-param}] %c - %m%n" />
        </Console>
        <AccessLog name="accessLogAppender" />
        <Async name="asyncAccessLogAppender">
            <AppenderRef ref="accessLogAppender" />
        </Async>

        <Loggers>
        <Logger name="AccessFileLogger" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
            <AppenderRef ref="asyncAccessLogAppender" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="off" />
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And Custom Log Appender is

```
package test.package
@Plugin(name = "AccessLog", category = "Core", elementType = "appender", printObject = true)
public final class AccessLogAppender extends AbstractAppender
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final ReadWriteLock rwLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock ();
    private final Lock readLock = rwLock.readLock ();

    private Connection connection = null;

    protected AccessLogAppender (final String name)
    {
        super (name, null, null);

        try
        {   

                connection = // code snippet to get the DB Connection 

        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {

        }
    }

    @PluginFactory
    public static AccessLogAppender createAppender (
            @PluginAttribute("name") String name)
    {
        return new AccessLogAppender (name);
    }

    @Override
    public void append (LogEvent event)
    {
        readLock.lock ();

        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        try
        {
            // code snippet to save the log into the DB

        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            readLock.unlock ();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop ()
    {
        if (connection != null)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.close ();
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                System.out.println (e.getMessage ());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And getting below error.

```
Caused by: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationException: No appenders are available for AsyncAppender asyncAccessLogAppender
```

Comment: So how is it supposed to log stuff on startup?

Comment: When application context provider is available, from that point only i need logs.

Comment: I mean, that's great but Spring is already logging before then which is why the logging is initialized before anything else.

Comment: Yes but i need to avoid it in one of the springboot docuemntation it is mentioned.

Comment: That's a logger not an appender.

Comment: it is log4j2 context right. So that means appenders will not work without loggers right. When log4j2 config file parsed then log appenders will be added to loggers.

Comment: Why not write to a file instead? Then periodically write that file to a DB. If there's any sort of high volume that generates a lot of log entries, it's going to cripple your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by making the DBConnection snippet as lazy loading in appenders. Then when the first call goes to appeners then DBConnection will be established. It works as expected.

```
package test.package
@Plugin(name = "AccessLog", category = "Core", elementType = "appender")
public final class AccessLogAppender extends AbstractAppender
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final ReadWriteLock rwLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock ();
    private final Lock readLock = rwLock.readLock ();

    private Connection connection = null;

    protected AccessLogAppender (final String name)
    {
        super (name, null, null);
    }
    private void init() {
if(connection == null) {
    try
        {   

                connection = // code snippet to get the DB Connection 

        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {

        }
     }
}

    @PluginFactory
    public static AccessLogAppender createAppender (
            @PluginAttribute("name") String name)
    {
        return new AccessLogAppender (name);
    }

    @Override
    public void append (LogEvent event)
    {
        init();
        readLock.lock ();

        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        try
        {
            // code snippet to save the log into the DB

        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            readLock.unlock ();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop ()
    {
        if (connection != null)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.close ();
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                System.out.println (e.getMessage ());
            }
        }
    }
}
```